# Добавление записей в нормализованную БД

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

Например, у менять есть `DataSet`, с тремя табличками: первая содержит ФИО, вторая город проживания, третья `ID`шники из первой и второй таблицы.
Объясните пожалуйста, в общих чертах, как добавлять новые записи в такую БД? Т.е. меня интересует не конкретный код, а теория.

Перед добавлением города, нужно проверять есть ли уже такой город в таблице? Или есть более адекватное решение?

Comment: То есть связь многие-ко-многим?

Comment: Да, Entity Framework.

Comment: Сначала делаете `select` `id`шника из таблицы городов с указанием в условии введенного города. Если корректного `id` возвращено не было, то добавляете новый город в таблицу, после чего вносите данные в таблицы ФИО и связей.

Comment: а сделать название города индексным полем?! тогда сама бд будет проверять на уникальность, ведь скорее всего надо будет осуществлять поиск по названию города? что то типа поле autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тут многое зависит от конкретной реализации и задачи.

Скорее всего на интерфейсе для города будет список. Следовательно у вас уже будет айдишник выбранного города при вставке в третью таблицу связей.

В случае добавления города, нужно будет проверять уникальность по названию. Это тоже можно по разному реализовать.